# Trying to write END_DOCUMENT when document has no root (ie. trying to output empty document, while writing Xml at \n1| %dw 2.0\n

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I see the error like "Trying to write END_DOCUMENT when document has no root" while I use the mentioned

Script:

```
%dw 2.0 
output application/xml
ns ns0 urn:astrazeneca:na:Activity:domain:3 
---
payload.ns0#Interactions.ns0#Interaction.ns0#InteractionId.ns0#ID
```

Input:

```
<Interactions>
    <Interaction>
        <InteractionId>
            <ID SystemCode="VNA">a044U00002GXVN1QAP</ID>
        </InteractionId>
        <InteractionDetails ></InteractionDetails>
        <Activity CreatedOnDate="2021-01-04T18:13:15">
            <ActivityId>
                <ns2:ID SystemCode="VNA">a084U00001dFR7aQAG</ns2:ID>
            </ActivityId>
        </Activity>
    </Interaction>
</Interactions>
```

Comment: used the below code in transfer message.
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns ns0 urn:astrazeneca:na:Activity:domain:3
---
payload.ns0#Interactions.ns0#Interaction.ns0#InteractionId.ns0#ID

Comment: You should edit the question to add the example. You need also to provide the input data, and the complete error message with all its lines, so it is possible to reproduce and understand the issue.

Comment: Find the error message and both input and transfer message code:
error:Trying to write END_DOCUMENT when document has no root (ie. trying to output empty document

Comment: trnasfer message code:
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns ns0 urn:astrazeneca:na:Activity:domain:3
---
payload.ns0#Interactions.ns0#Interaction.ns0#InteractionId.ns0#ID
input:
<Interactions>
  <Interaction>
    <InteractionId>
      <ID SystemCode="VNA">a044U00002GXVN1QAP</ID>
    </InteractionId>
    <InteractionDetails >
    </InteractionDetails>
    <Activity CreatedOnDate="2021-01-04T18:13:15" >
      <ActivityId>
        <ns2:ID SystemCode="VNA">a084U00001dFR7aQAG</ns2:ID>
      </ActivityId>
    </Activity>
 </Interaction>
</Interactions>

Comment: Please edit the question and add the additional information in there. Kindly note that your input has no namespaces but the script is expecting namespaces. Either change the input to match the script or change the script to match the input.

Comment: I have edited the question on your behalf. Please see my comment about the namespace and also add the complete error.

Answer (score 1):

There is missing information and the example input doesn't match the script to be sure, however it looks like the script is trying to output a single value ("a044U00002GXVN1QAP") in XML format. That is invalid because a string is not a valid XML. You need to define a root element in the output so it can generate a valid XML.

Example (removing namespace for simplicity):

```
%dw 2.0 
output application/xml
---
{ someRoot: payload.Interactions.Interaction.InteractionId.ID }
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<someRoot>a044U00002GXVN1QAP</someRoot>
```

If you are just trying to output that id to be processed later in the flow just change the output to `application/java` instead so it doesn't require a root element and it is much more efficient, avoiding the extra XML formatting/parsing.